# No matching constructor for initialization of 'class'

Tags: c++, generics

I have this class named Person, and I want to use the show function in main. But for some reason, it is giving a No matching constructor for initialization of 'Person' error. I'm trying to print out the person name and age and my sorting runs fine, it is just this error and I don't know how to fix it

```
class Person {
public:
    string name;
    int age;

public:
    Person(string name, int age) {
        this->name = move(name);
        this->age = age;
    }
    void show() {
        cout << name << ": " << age << endl;
    }
.
.
.
int main() {
vector<Person> list = {
                Person("Smith", 20),
                Person("Andrew", 31),
                Person("Beck", 19)
};
Person person; // Error
mySort(&people, Person::sortName());
for (auto value: list) {
    person.show(); // I'm trying to use show function
}
```

Comment: I get `error: 'string' does not name a type` from this code.   And other errors about missing brackets and semicolons.  Is this a [mre]?  Is this your actual, complete code?

Comment: This isn't the complete, it is just a minimal reproducible example, but I was just hoping from looking at it, you can tell me I can properly use the show() function in main.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example is reproducible. A code snippet isn't going to run, so it's not reproducible. As much as we like minimal, if it can't be used to demonstrate the problem it all its glory, the example's usefulness is diminished. Sometimes fatally.

Comment: To be clear: this is **not** a [mre] because the code you show us does not produce [the error you show us](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/Y8qooEcdK).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a default constructor, so you cannot write `Person person`; you need to write something like `Person person("Smith", 20);`. However, there are some other issues with the code:

- Don't write `this->memvar`, you can write `memvar` inside the class; in the constructor, use initialization list (`Person(string name, int age) : name(name), age(age) {}`)
- Try to avoid `using namespace std;`, it's a source of name clashes when you do real programming.
- It's not clear what `person` would mean
- In the `for`-loop, you assign `value`, yet you call `show()` on person. Also, you don't take the elem by reference (`auto& value`)
- I can't see `shortName()` and `mySort()`, so I can't reason about them.